# How to append a char at a defined position

Tags: c, string

I'm trying to add a character at a defined position. I've created a new function, allocate a memory for one more char, save characters after the position then added my character at the defined position, and now I don't know how to erase characters after that position to concatenate the saved string. Any solution?

Here is the beginning of my function:

```
void appendCharact(char *source, char carac, int position) {
    source = realloc(source, strlen(source) * sizeof(char) + 1); //Get enough memory
    char *temp = source.substr(position); //Save characters after my position
    source[position] = carac; //Add the character
}
```

EDIT :
I'm trying to implement another "barbarous" solution, in debug mode I can see that I've approximately my new string but it look like I can't erase the older pointer...

```
void appendCharact(char *source, char carac, int position) {
    char *temp = (char *)malloc((strlen(source) + 2) * sizeof(char));
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < position; i++) {
        temp[i] = source[i];
    }

    temp[position] = carac;
    for (i = position; i < strlen(source); i++) {
        temp[i + 1] = source[i];
    }
    temp[strlen(temp) + 1] = '\0';
    free(source);
    source = temp;
}
```

Comment: C or C++? They are two *very* different languages.

Comment: Oops sorry, C++ I've updated

Comment: Then the solution is *very* simple: Use [`std::string`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) and pass by reference.

Comment: Actually you are using alloc or realloc that is not very good practice in C++ you should use new() to allocate memory in C++

Comment: As it is, the code you show have at least five major problems (but one happens to work anyway due to pure luck I would say). There might be more major problems depending on how the function is called.

Comment: Nice, 4 lines and 5 majors problems... I'm a beginner in C++ i'll try to solve that. Thanks. And about using std::string I can't find a function to erase characters from a defined index. Should I divide my char* to a substring to make a manipulation ?
EDIT : Never Mind, found the function "replace()"

Comment: I can add an answer listing the five problems if you like? :)

Comment: Of course I want !

Comment: When you see C code referring to `char *` as a "string", it just means a sequence of characters ending with `'\0'`. It's not _at all_ the same as the C++ `std::string`. So you can't call methods like `std::string::substr()` on a `char *`. It isn't an object and doesn't have any methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your new solution is much closer to a working function but it still has some problems:

- you do not check for `malloc()` failure.
- you should avoid computing the length of the source string multiple times.
- `temp[strlen(temp) + 1] = '\0';` is incorrect as `temp` is not yet a proper C string and `strlen(temp) + 1` would point beyond the allocated block anyway, you should just write `temp[i + 1] = '\0';`
- the newly allocated string should be returned to the caller, either as the return value or via a `char **` argument.

Here is a corrected version:

```
char *insertCharact(char *source, char carac, size_t position) {
    size_t i, len;
    char *temp;

    len = source ? strlen(source) : 0;
    temp = (char *)malloc(len + 2);
    if (temp != NULL) {
        /* sanitize position */
        if (position > len)
            position = len;
        /* copy initial portion */
        for (i = 0; i < position; i++) {
            temp[i] = source[i];
        }
        /* insert new character */
        temp[i] = carac;
        /* copy remainder of the source string if any */
        for (; i < len; i++) {
            temp[i + 1] = source[i];
        }
        /* set the null terminator */
        temp[i + 1] = '\0';
        free(source);
    }
    return temp;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I mentioned that I could see five problems with the code as shown (copied here for reference)

```
void appendCharact(char * source, char carac , int position)
{
    source = realloc(source, strlen(source) * sizeof(char) + 1); //Get enough memory
    char * temp = source.substr(position); //Save characters after my position
    source[position] = carac; //Add the charactere
}
```

The problems are (in no specific order):

1. `strlen(source) * sizeof(char) + 1` is equal to `(strlen(source) * sizeof(char)) + 1`. It should have been `(strlen(source) + 1) * sizeof(char)`. However, this works fine since `sizeof(char)` is defined in the C++ specification to *always* be equal to `1`.
2. Related to the above: Simple `char` strings are really called ***null-terminated*** byte strings. As such they must be terminated by a "null" character (`'\0'`). This null character of course needs space in the allocated string, and is *not* counted by `strlen`. Therefore to add a character you need allocate `strlen(source) + 2` characters.
3. Never assign back to the pointer you pass to [`realloc`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/c/realloc). If `realloc` fails, it will return a null pointer, making you lose the original memory, and that is a memory leak.
4. The [`realloc`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/c/realloc) function return type is `void*`. In C++ you need to cast it to the correct pointer type for assignment.
5. You pass `source` by *value*, meaning inside the function you have a local *copy* of the pointer. When you assign to `source` you only assign to the local copy, the original pointer used in the call will not be modified.

---

Here are some other problems with the code, or its possible use:

- Regarding the null-terminator, once you allocate enough memory for it you also need to add it to the string.
- If the function is called with `source` being a literal string or an array or anything that wasn't returned by a previous call to `malloc`, `calloc` or `realloc`, then you can't pass that pointer to `realloc`.
- You use `source.substr(position)` which is not possible since `source` isn't an object and therefore doesn't have member functions.

Comment: Ok, a lot of problems because I didn't try to build the solution before. Now my main question is : Is a char * considerate as a string in C++ ? if not there is any solution to cast it ? otherwise; when it's cast, can I cast it back as char * ? Thank you for the time you took to answer me

Comment: @TotoNaBendo A `char*` variable can point to the first character of a null-terminated array, and that makes it a "string" in that sense.

Comment: All of your points are valid, but the question remains unanswered.

Comment: Well, sorry. Thanks you everyone for taking the time to help me.

Answer (score 1):

```
int pos = 1;
char toInsert = '-';
std::string text = "hallo";
std::stringstream buffer;
buffer << text.substr(0,pos);
buffer << toInsert;
buffer << text.substr(pos);
text = buffer.str();
```

Comment: Hello, first thanks you for your answer. I would like more explanation about your solution : 
Is a char* considerate as a std::string ? or should I make any conversion ? because i want my function to be a in/out function and I can't change the type of my source.

Comment: do you need a c or c++ solution? char* is c-style

Comment: I'm sorry, I think this is ambiguous, i've made a C++ solution to code in C inside because I can't make a C solution on visual studio , only c++ solution is available, so yes, I need a C solution, my mistake

Answer (score 1):

Try using something like:

```
 #include <string>
 void appendCharAt(std::string& src, char c , int pos)
 {
     std::string front(src.begin(), src.begin() + pos - 1 ); // use iterators
     std::string back(src.begin() + pos, src.end() );
     src = front + c + back; // concat together +-operator is overloaded for strings
 }
```

Not 100% sure weather the positions are right. Maybe front hast to be src.begin() + pos and back src.begin() + pos + 1. Just try it out.

Answer (score 1):

The C version of this will have to take care of the situation where realloc fails, in which case the original string is preserved. You should only overwrite the old pointer with the one returned from realloc upon success.

It might look something like this:

```
bool append_ch (char** str, char ch, size_t pos)
{
  size_t prev_size = strlen(*str) + 1;
  char* tmp = realloc(*str, prev_size+1);
  if(tmp == NULL)
  {
    return false;
  }

  memmove(&tmp[pos+1], &tmp[pos], prev_size-pos);
  tmp[pos] = ch;
  *str = tmp;
  return true;
}
```

Usage:

```
const char test[] = "hello word";
char* str = malloc(sizeof test);
memcpy(str, test, sizeof test);
puts(str);

bool ok = append_ch(&str, 'l', 9); 
if(!ok) 
  asm ("HCF");  // error handling here
puts(str);

free(str);
```

Comment: Hi first, thank you for your answer. I'm trying to understand your solution, why using a double array (**char) ?

Comment: @TotoNaBendo Because you need to pass the new address returned from realloc back to the caller. From the C spec: "The realloc function deallocates the old object pointed to by ptr and returns a
pointer to a new object that has the size specified by size. The contents of the new
object shall be the same as that of the old object prior to deallocation, up to the lesser of
the new and old sizes."

Comment: So realloc is a function that should be used carefully, since it makes it easy to shoot yourself in the foot. One of the reasons why C++ didn't include it. (In C++ it is preferred to rather blow your whole leg off, when accidentally mixing up `new` and `new[]`.)

Comment: Thank a lot for your explanation, unfortunately I will not use your solution, otherwise, I have to change 90% of my program because of that double array. So actually i'm looking for a solution more barbabous as this is for a personnal project. I've edited with the begining of another solution.

Comment: Good solution, you do test for `realloc` success but not for `pos` consistency with the current string contents. You might just add `if (pos >= prev_size) pos = prev_size - 1;`. It is also questionable to name `append_ch` a function that *inserts* a character inside a string.

Comment: @TotoNaBendo You could as well return the new pointer but that requires the caller to always use the function correctly and we get the same oddity as is built-in with realloc. Namely that we can't do `str = append_ch(str, ch, pos);` or risk memory leaks.

Comment: @chqrlie Error handling is mostly left to the caller here, which is fine as long as it is documented.